# Matching Unicode word boundaries in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode

In order to match the Unicode word boundaries [as defined in the [Annex #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundary_Rules)] in Python, I have been using the `regex` package with flags `regex.WORD | regex.V1` (`regex.UNICODE` should be default since the pattern is a Unicode string) in the following way:

```
>>> s="here are some words"
>>> regex.findall(r'\w(?:\B\S)*', s, flags = regex.V1 | regex.WORD)
['here', 'are', 'some', 'words']
```

It works well in this rather simple cases. However, I was wondering what is the expected behavior in case the input string contains certain punctuation. It seems to me that [WB7](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#WB7) says that for example the apostrophe in `x'z` does not qualify as a word boundary which seems to be indeed the case:

```
>>> regex.findall(r'\w(?:\B\S)*', "x'z", flags = regex.V1 | regex.WORD)
["x'z"]
```

However, if there is a vowel, the situation changes:

```
>>> regex.findall(r'\w(?:\B\S)*', "l'avion", flags = regex.V1 | regex.WORD)
["l'", 'avion']
```

This would suggest that the regex module implements the rule `WB5a` mentioned in the standard in the *Notes* section. However, this rule also says that the behavior should be the same with `\u2019` (right single quotation mark) which I can't reproduce:

```
>>> regex.findall(r'\w(?:\B\S)*', "l\u2019avion", flags = regex.V1 | regex.WORD)
['l’avion']
```

Moreover, even with "normal" apostrophe, a ligature (or `y`) seems to behave as a "non-vowel":

```
>>> regex.findall(r'\w(?:\B\S)*', "l'œil", flags = regex.V1 | regex.WORD)
["l'œil"]
>>> regex.findall(r'\w(?:\B\S)*', "J'y suis", flags = regex.V1 | regex.WORD)
["J'y", 'suis']
```

Is this the expected behavior? (all examples above were executed with regex 2.4.106 and Python 3.5.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- *RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK  `’`* seems to be just simply missed in [source file](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/f21447bf288780d8dd9b1633820480484ce8f677/regex_3/regex/_regex.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#_regex.c-1657):

```
/* Break between apostrophe and vowels (French, Italian). */
/* WB5a */
if (pos_m1 >= 0 && char_at(state->text, pos_m1) == '\'' &&
  is_unicode_vowel(char_at(state->text, text_pos)))
    return TRUE;
```

2- Unicode vowels are determined with [`is_unicode_vowel()`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/f21447bf288780d8dd9b1633820480484ce8f677/regex_3/regex/_regex.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#_regex.c-1522) function which translates to this list:

```
a, à, á, â, e, è, é, ê, i, ì, í, î, o, ò, ó, ô, u, ù, ú, û
```

So a [LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256) `œ` character is not considered as a unicode vowel:

```
Py_LOCAL_INLINE(BOOL) is_unicode_vowel(Py_UCS4 ch) {
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03030000
    switch (Py_UNICODE_TOLOWER(ch)) {
#else
    switch (Py_UNICODE_TOLOWER((Py_UNICODE)ch)) {
#endif
    case 'a': case 0xE0: case 0xE1: case 0xE2:
    case 'e': case 0xE8: case 0xE9: case 0xEA:
    case 'i': case 0xEC: case 0xED: case 0xEE:
    case 'o': case 0xF2: case 0xF3: case 0xF4:
    case 'u': case 0xF9: case 0xFA: case 0xFB:
        return TRUE;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**This bug is now fixed in regex 2016.08.27 after a [bug report](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/issues/219/unicode-word-boundries).** [[_regex.c:#1668](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/63d0aacd9395318daeb3ff8bf8696a7651528415/regex_3/regex/_regex.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#_regex.c-1668)]

Comment: Point 1 sure looks like a bug, and I suggest you report it, if you haven't already.  It's hard to say about point 2.  Searching for "vowel" on unicode.org gives a number of hits for various Asian languages, but nothing about French or Italian.  The OP's examples certainly seem correct, but I can't see that Annex 29 addresses them specifically.